# What are the Esperanto words for Hindi, Urdu, Farsi, and Tamil?

Tags: translation, single-word-requests

I'm putting together a flash card deck of world languages and I can't seem to find these on a dictionary I trust. I have Persian as "persa" but I would like a word for Farsi.

Answer (score 8):

**According to [this](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Listo_de_lingvoj):**

Hindi = la hindia [lingvo]

Urdu = Urduo

Tamil = la tamila [lingvo]

Farsi = la persa [lingvo]

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'm guessing Urdu is probably Urdua though.

Comment: @KyleBailey Some languages whose name isn't based on a people or the name of a country have their own word root and so end in o. For example Esperanto and Latino. According to PMEG Urdu also falls into this category. http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/propraj_nomoj/landoj_popoloj_lingvoj.html#i-r76

Comment: @NeilRoberts Interesting, I didn't know that. I imagine in casual speech you will find many people falling into overregularization and saying "la urdua", that's certainly what I would have done.